# How can I use CSS to keep content in its own column?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out why my sidebar content (right column) wraps around into the content column (left column) when the content in the sidebar it a greater height than the content column.

**Link to my Page**
http://www.foothillertech.com/student/webdesign/2015/4th/04_50/tinker/divLayout/index.php

**Link to my css**
http://www.foothillertech.com/student/webdesign/2015/4th/04_50/tinker/divLayout/divLayout.css
http://www.foothillertech.com/student/webdesign/2015/4th/04_50/tinker/layout/reset.css

I am not a css expert, I understand the basics, but not the finer details of every property and how the interact with others. I built this layout using a few different tutorials that were written for HTML5, but I'm using standard  tags.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

**Original HTML**

```
    <div id="container">

   <!-- header -->  
   <div id="header">
      <h1 id="title">Responsive Layout</h1>
   </div>


   <!-- Navigation -->  
   <div id="menu" class="clearfix">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div> 

   <!-- Main Content area -->
   <div id="content">
      <h2>Built with CSS3 and HTML5</h2>
      <!-- Main content -->  
      <p>Responsive design has become a must for a website these days. More than 50%+ of the people who have access to internet use some kind of mobile device, such as tablets, phones etc. And if your website is does not respond correctly to their device size, then it’s most likely a lost customer for you.
  Responsive design has become a must for a website these days. More than 50%+ of the people who have access to internet use some kind of mobile device, such as tablets, phones etc. And if your website is does not respond correctly to their device size, then it’s most likely a lost customer for you.Responsive design has become a must for a website these days. More than 50%+ of the people who have access to internet use some kind of mobile device, such as tablets, phones etc. And if your website is does not respond correctly to their device size, then it’s most likely a lost customer for you.</p>   </div>

   <!-- Sidebar -->
   <div  id="sidebar">
      <h3>This is the Sidebar</h3>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>    
         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>   
         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>       
         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>      
         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Sidebar content -->     
   </div>

   <!-- Footer -->
   <div id="footer" class="clearfix">
      Footer
   </div>

</div>
```

**Original CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

.clearfix {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}


#container{
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 1200px;
}
#header {
   width: 94%;
   padding: 3%;
   background-color: #FF5722;
}

#header #title {
   font-size: 50px;
   color: #fff;
}

#menu {
   width: 97%;
   background-color: #E64A19;
   padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.5%;
}

#menu ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 15px 1.5% 15px 1.5% ;
}

#menu ul li a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 1.2em;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
}

#content {
   float: left;
   padding: 3%;
   width: 64%;
}
#aside {
   float: right;
   padding: 3%;
   width: 24%;
   background-color: #eee;
}
#footer{
   width: 94%;
   padding: 3%;
   background-color: #FF5722;
   border-top: 5px solid #E64A19;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
}

@media all and (max-width : 768px) {

   #header {
      text-align: center;
   }

   #menu {
      text-align: center;
   }

   #content {
      width: 94%;
      padding: 3%;   
   }

   #sidebar {
      width: 94%;
      padding: 3%;
      border-top: 3px solid #E64A19;
   }

}
@media all and (max-width : 330px) {

   #menu ul li {
      display:block;
      width: 94%;
   }

}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin: 0 0 16px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    font-size:14px;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #333;
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 24px;
    margin: 0 0 2.4rem;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 Thank you, you are correct. I've added the original code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple as far I understand. use float right to the sidebar and it will stay like that without breaking

```css
div#sidebar{ float: right;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're making the layout responsive you might want to consider displaying the content and sidebar as inline-blocks, instead of using floats. It works better cross browser and you won't have to clear your divs. Try this:

```
#content{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:3%;
    width:64%;
}

#sidebar{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```